# Is there a way to return a local object with destructor?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, heap-memory, lifetime

I have a class **Foo** that have a constructor that receives 2 ints and create a dynamic array in 2D in heap, and the destructor deletes it.
The problem is that i'm creating a function operator+ that adds two values of 2 objects, and, when returning the new object containing the add, it calls the destructor making the internal variable, allocated in heap, free.

```
class foo()
{
    foo() { }
    foo(int a, int b){ ... } // Allocate 2D array
    ~foo() { ... } // Deallocate 2D array
    void read() { ... }
    void operator=(foo& A) { .. }


    foo operator+(foo& A)
    {
        foo ans(2,2);
        // Perform logic to add *this obj with A
        ...
        return ans;
    }
}

int main()
{
    foo A(2,2), B(2,2);
    foo C;
    A.read(); 
    B.read();
    C = A + B;
    return 0;
}
```

So, when A+B is called, all the operation is completed but, when returning the object, it will call the destructor of **ans** and deleting all of the information stored.

One way to solve this it was by returning a **pointer** to this "ans" memory (allocating it), but the problem is that i don't want to operate with pointers in the main function, and storing it in heap only for a simple ecuation isn't good.

The other way (that i'm actually using) is by creating an **operator+=** so the code in int main gets like this:

```
    foo A(2,2), B(2,2);
    A.read(); 
    B.read();
    C = A;
    C += A;
```

With this operation I'm actually modifying the C itself and, previously, copied all the info from A to C. Is not the best way but it was the only that I manage it.

Comment: whenever I read "obvious" it points to something that isnt obvious. Please include a [mcve]

Comment: Your `operator+` function return `ans` by *value*, which means it will be *copied* before `ans` is destructed.

Comment: If `foo` manages memory, you need to follow the [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three): you're missing a copy constructor that allocates fresh memory. Alternatively, use a `std::shared_ptr` or `std::vector` for your "obviously on the heap" data structure and be happy.

Comment: Also please note that  your question title is misleading. You're not trying to return a "local class", you're trying to return a local *object*.